# Why my dispatcher is firing only once ngrx

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have a login flow setup. Let say i have this scenario, user clicks in the login button with wrong credentials, i dispatch a login action and expect the bad results from the API, i show error with an error handler in UI, user puts new credentials which are still not the right ones, i should be able to repeat the process above.

Well for me is not happening. the dispatcher is firing only once. I am new to ngrx and not sure where i am doing wrong but here is my code:

Login Method:

```
logInUser(user: User) {    
  this.store$.dispatch(new fromUserActions.LoginUser(user));
  this.actions$.ofType(fromUserActions.LOGIN_USER_FAIL);
}
```

Side Effect:

```
@Effect()
loginUser$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType(fromUserActions.LOGIN_USER),
        map((action: fromUserActions.LoginUser) => action.payload),
        switchMap(payload => this.userService.loginUser(payload)),
        map((user) => fromUserActions.LoginUserSuccess(user)),
        catchError((error) => of(new fromUserActions.LoginUserFail(error.message)))
    );
```

Fail Action:

```
export class LoginUserFail implements Action {
   readonly type = LOGIN_USER_FAIL;

 constructor(public payload: any) { }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the redux dev tools. As you can see the first time action login and fail are just working fine, afterwards only login action fires.

[image]

Comment: how does your store change in case of **LOGIN_USER_FAIL**?

Answer (score 1):

You have to catch the error on the inner observable `this.userService.loginUser(payload)`.

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/effects/book.effects.ts#L51

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ***this.actions$.ofType(fromUserActions.LOGIN_USER_FAIL);***. Just remove it.

```
logInUser(user: User) {    
  this.store$.dispatch(new fromUserActions.LoginUser(user));
  this.actions$.ofType(fromUserActions.LOGIN_USER_FAIL); <--- Remove
}
```

And you have pipe the response of api call.

```
    @Effect()
    loginUser$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType(fromUserActions.LOGIN_USER),
        map((action: fromUserActions.LoginUser) => action.payload),
        switchMap(
            payload => this.userService.loginUser(payload).pipe(
                map((user) => new fromUserActions.LoginUserSuccess(user)),
                catchError((error) => new fromUserActions.LoginUserFail(error.message))
            )
        ),

    );
```